# Tensorflow error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, conda

I'm having issues with running tensorflow.

Important! I have already looked through other threads - they didn't solve my problem.

I'm on a MAC.

It looks like it got installed, but when on Jupyter I'm running

```
import tensorflow as ft
```

I get the error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

What I tried:

In the beginning I tried installing it with python 3.6 - that didn't work as during the pip installation process it ended with a fail saying i need python >= 3.7

OK, I created a new envt:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.9

pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
 
conda install tensorflow
```

all ran successfully.

I can run now

```
pip show tensorflow
```

it gives me

```
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.11.0
```

However the error in Jupyter still remains.

I tried installing it on **PyCharm** - it runs well, but not in Jupyter.

PyCharm is using python v. 3.9 (same as my tensorflow env)

And if I check my python v. in Jupyter, it's also 3.9

I even tried restarting my laptop to see if maybe that would help, but no.

Please give me ideas if any, what else could work.

Many thanks!

Comment: This does not seem to be related to tensorflow but to how your virtual environments are set up. Check which one your are using in PyCharm and which one your are using to run Jupyter.

Comment: Both are versions 3.9

Comment: That's interesting however, when i run pip show tensorflow, the path it gives me is
anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages
could this be the problem?..

Comment: That's not the point. It seems Jupyter is started in the wrong or without any venv.

Comment: How can I start Jupyter in the right env? I mean I create an env in terminal, I activate it. What else can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this is related to tf itself, more likely related to the imports and the enviroment.

Things you can try:

1. Activate your tensorflow environment in Jupyter: "conda activate tensorflow"
2. Install tensorflow in the base environment: "conda install tensorflow"
3. Check your Jupyter environment: make sure that you are running it in the same environment where tensorflow is installed "conda info --envs"
4. Reinstall Jupyter: If none of the above steps work, you can try reinstalling Jupyter "conda deactivate" to exit the tensorflow environment, "conda install jupyter" and "conda activate tensorflow" again to activate the environment.

Comment: I was able to make it run and the solution was to re-install anaconda and run pip install tensorflow again directly in my bash environment.